# Skip all validations on state machine method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

I am trying to figure out how to skip validations on a specific instance of an ActiveRecord object when my reservation model transitions on state machine via a rake task. I would like to skip all validations whenever reservation.close! is called. Would hope to call something like reservation.close!(:validate => false). FYI we are using https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine for state machine.

Here is a sample of my reservation model.

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :ride_id, :start_at, :end_at, presence: true
    validate  :proper_custom_price?, allow_nil: true, on: :update
    validate  :dates_valid?
    validate  :dates_make_sense?

    scope :needs_close_transition, lambda { where("end_at < ?", Time.now).where("state" => ["requested", "negotiating", "approved"]) }

    state_machine :initial => 'requested' do

      all_prebooked = ["requested", "negotiating", "approved"]

      event :close do
        transition :from => all_prebooked,
          :to   => "precanceled"
        end

        before_transition :on => [:close] do |reservation|
          reservation.cancel_reason = :admin
        end
     end
end
```

Here is a sample of my rake task.

```
namespace :reservation do

  task :close => :environment do
    puts "== close"

    Reservation.needs_close_transition.each do |reservation|
      puts "===> #{reservation.id}"

      begin
        reservation.close!(:validate => false)
      rescue Exception => e
        Airbrake.notify(e, error_message: e.message) if defined?(Airbrake)
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: You use aasm gem? Did you try defining `close!` method?

Comment: We are using this state machine gem https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine

Comment: Not sure if it's a good choice, this gem haven't been updated for over a year! Anyway if I understand docs correctly you could just try to redefine this method.

Comment: I believe this method is implied from the close event within the state machine. Is that correct? In that case how would I go about redefining the close method to skip validations?

Comment: hm... by doing `def close!` in model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the state_machine gem, the `state` attribute is updated before the validations are run, so you can add an unless condition to the validation that tests the current state:

```
validates :start_at, :end_at, presence: true, unless: Proc.new {state == 'closed'}
```

If you want more complex logic, pass a method name symbox to `unless` instead of a proc:

```
validates :start_at, :end_at, presence: true, unless: :requires_validation?

def requires_validation?
  # complex logic to determine if the record should be validated
end
```

Comment: This worked for me. I just checked if the state was precancled and if so I bypassed the validation. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, however I did not want to alter my current validations, so I checked the state machine code (version 1.2.0) and I found another solution, for your specific case it would be something like:

```
reservation.close!(false)
reservation.save(validate: false)
```

That will trigger all callbacks that you have defined in your state machine, and well this solution is working well for me.

Comment: I prefer this solution, because you disable all the validations at once.